# pull a column from a select function and add it on an existing select query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to get an output where I am adding another column to an existing select query.

```
SELECT 
product_category, 
COUNT (product_category)
FROM marketingimpression
GROUP BY product_category
```

1st output

[image]

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT (is_click) FROM marketingimpression
WHERE is_click = true
GROUP BY product_category
```

2nd output

[image]

Is there a way to get these 2 combined?

The data are in the same table.

Comment: People tend not to (a) click links or (b) deal with teeny-tiny images. If you follow the guidelines and convert those to text people can read you'll have a better chance of getting a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a way to do it :

```
SELECT COUNT (product_category) as count_categories, COUNT (case when is_click=true then 1 end) as count_click
FROM marketingimpression 
GROUP BY product_category
```

`DISTINCT` is not needed since you will get one count per product_category